# ¿Cómo poner en español el calendario de PrimeVue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primefaces, primevue

Estoy trabajando con los componentes de **PrimeVue**, más específicamente el [Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/calendar).

En la sección **"Localization"** de su documentación se explica que para poder poner el calendario en otro idioma como el español, hay que usar el bind `:locale="es"`, quedando todo el componente así:

```
<Calendar
   id="spanish"
   v-model="date2"
   :locale="es"
   dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
/>
```

Luego en `data()` hay que definir cada parámetro en español de esta manera:

```
data() {
    return {
      
      es: {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: [
          "Domingo",
          "Lunes",
          "Martes",
          "Miércoles",
          "Jueves",
          "Viernes",
          "Sábado",
        ],
        dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb"],
        dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
        monthNames: [
          "Enero",
          "Febrero",
          "Marzo",
          "Abril",
          "Mayo",
          "Junio",
          "Julio",
          "Agosto",
          "Septiembre",
          "Octubre",
          "Noviembre",
          "Diciembre",
        ],
        monthNamesShort: [
          "Ene",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Abr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Ago",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dic",
        ],
        today: "Hoy",
        clear: "Borrar",
        weekHeader: "Sm",
      },
     
    };
```

Seguí esas recomendaciones, pero no consigo que el calendario salga en español.

Todo mi código me quedaría así:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h5>Calendario español</h5>
    <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
      <label for="spanish">Spanish</label>
      <Calendar
        id="spanish"
        v-model="date2"
        :locale="es"
        dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let prevMonth = month === 0 ? 11 : month - 1;
    let prevYear = prevMonth === 11 ? year - 1 : year;
    let nextMonth = month === 11 ? 0 : month + 1;
    let nextYear = nextMonth === 0 ? year + 1 : year;
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setMonth(prevMonth);
    this.minDate.setFullYear(prevYear);
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setMonth(nextMonth);
    this.maxDate.setFullYear(nextYear);

    let invalidDate = new Date();
    invalidDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    this.invalidDates = [today, invalidDate];
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date1: null,
      date2: null,
      date3: null,
      date4: null,
      date5: null,
      date6: null,
      date7: null,
      date8: null,
      date9: null,
      date10: null,
      date11: null,
      date12: null,
      date13: null,
      date14: null,
      dates1: null,
      dates2: null,
      es: {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: [
          "Domingo",
          "Lunes",
          "Martes",
          "Miércoles",
          "Jueves",
          "Viernes",
          "Sábado",
        ],
        dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb"],
        dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
        monthNames: [
          "Enero",
          "Febrero",
          "Marzo",
          "Abril",
          "Mayo",
          "Junio",
          "Julio",
          "Agosto",
          "Septiembre",
          "Octubre",
          "Noviembre",
          "Diciembre",
        ],
        monthNamesShort: [
          "Ene",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Abr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Ago",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dic",
        ],
        today: "Hoy",
        clear: "Borrar",
        weekHeader: "Sm",
      },
      minDate: null,
      maxDate: null,
      invalidDates: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.special-day {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

[image: Edit new]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeVUE ofrece 2 formas de cambiar el idioma:

## Global

En tu `main.js` agrega los elementos dentro del objeto `locale` cuando uses `PrimeVue`:

```
// Vue 2
Vue.use(PrimeVue, {
    locale: {
        dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
        dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "..."],
        monthNames: ["Enero", "..."],
        // ... más configuraciones
    }
});
```

[image: Edit new]

---

```
// Vue 3
app.use(PrimeVue, {
    locale: {
        dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
        dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "..."],
        monthNames: ["Enero", "..."],
        // ... más configuraciones
    }
});
```

[image: Edit new]

## Por componente

Si tu aplicación es de multilenguaje, podrás cambiar el lenguaje de PrimeVUE cualquier momento con `this.$primevue.config.locale`, por ejemplo:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        changeToSpanish() {
            this.$primevue.config.locale.monthNames = ["Enero", "..."];
            this.$primevue.config.locale.dayNames: = [ '...' ];
            // ... más configuraciones
        }
    }
}
```

### Recursos

Todas las opciones para configurar las puedes encontrar:

- [Para Vue 2](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/locale)
- [Para Vue 3](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/locale)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Anteriormente ya había intentado cambiar el idioma de manera **Global** incluyendo la configuración en mi `main.js`, pero recibo el siguiente warning al compilar mi App: `"export 'createApp' was not found in 'vue'`. ¿Podría tratarse de un problema de compatibilidad con mi versión de Vue como sugiere [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308560/15385861)? Yo uso la versión "2.6.11" de Vue en mi proyecto.

Comment: Correcto, entre Vue 3 y Vue 2 hay unas cuantas diferencias a la hora de crear la aplicación, en un momento agregó un sandbox para Vue 2 :D

Comment: Perfecto, ahora sí me funciona. Muchas gracias. Perdón mi ignorancia, pero vengo de React y soy nuevo en Vue